# How to create a where clause that returns no records in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Is there a good way to way generate a where clause that will never return any results?

**Use Case:** This search method generates a where clause. However, if the params are invalid, then is should still return a where clause. But the where clause should return no records.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def search params
    if invalid?(params)
      return where(...)
    end

    where(name: params[:name])
 end
```

One idea is to use `where(id:nil)`, but that does not express the intent clearly.

Rails 4.1.7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for the [`none`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-none) method.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an empty array, meaning "an empty set of desirable values":

```
Model.where(id: [])
```

This condition is transformed into something always false:

```
SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE 1=0
```

However, there is an even better way, `Model.none`. It's better because it doesn't interact with the database at all (in most cases). Because why do that if no entries will be fetched anyway? That assumption goes as far as to having this scope's `#to_sql` return an empty string, meaning no queries will be fired.

```
Model.none.to_sql
# => ""
```

Despite that, it's still usable as a subquery! However, the output is a bit surprising (non-empty!):

```
Model.from(Model.none, :models)

SELECT "models".* FROM (SELECT "models".* FROM "models" WHERE (1=0)) things
```

Yep, the same `1=0`.

So, **use `#none`** unless you're doing something absolutely crazy from ActiveRecord's perspective.